# Find the value of $C$

Tags: trigonometry

We have a triangle $ABC$. Whats the value of angle $C$?

$$\sin^2(A)+\sin^2(B)-\sin^2(C)=1$$

I made a small java program and it gave me an answer. I want to know how to make it through other ways.

Comment: As $\displaystyle A+B=\pi-C, \sin(A+B)=\sin(\pi-C)=\sin C$ and $\cos(A+B)=-\cos C$

$$\sin^2A+\sin(B+C)\sin(B-C)$$

$$=\sin A \sin(B+C)+\sin A\sin(B-C)$$

$$= \sin A\left[\sin(B+C)+\sin(B-C)\right]$$
$$=2\sin A\sin B\cos C$$
$$=\left[\cos(A-B)-\cos(A+B)\right]\cos C$$

$$=\cos(A-B)\cos C+\cos^2 C$$  But, I don't know where to go from here. Even the idea  of discriminant didn't help much

Comment: what was the answer available from java program?

Answer (score 1):

As @lab shows in a comment,
$$\sin^2 A + \sin^2 B - \sin^2 C = 1 \quad\implies\quad 2\sin A \sin B \cos C = 1$$
so we can write
$$1 = 2 \sin A \sin(A+C) \cos C = 2 \sin A \cos C( \sin A \cos C+ \cos A \sin C)$$
Thus,
$$\begin{align}
1 - 2 \sin^2 A \cos^2 C &= 2 \sin A \cos A \sin C \cos C \\
\implies \quad \left( 1 - 2 \sin^2 A \cos^2 C \right)^2 &= 4 \sin^2 A \cos^2 A \left( 1 - \cos^2 C \right) \cos^2 C \\
\implies \quad 4 a^2 c^2 ( 2 - a^2 - c^2 ) &= 1 \qquad (\star)
\end{align}$$
where $c := \cos C$ and $a := \sin A$. Equation $(\star)$ is a quadratic in $c^2$ (and $a^2$), yielding valid values for $C$ across a range of values of $A$ (and vice-versa); values for which $0 < A+C \leq \pi$, making for valid triangles. Without further restrictions, there's no single value for $C$.

Answer (score 0):

An isosceles triangle with angles of 90,45 and 45 comes to mind as a rather simple solution. Let A or B be one of the 90 degree angles since $sin^2(90)=1$ and the others will cancel out. Whether there is another solution one may use substitution since A+B+C=180.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B-\sin^2(A+B)=\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B-(\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A)^2=$$

$$=\sin^2 A+\sin^2 B-(\sin^2A\cos^2B+\sin^2B\cos^2A+2\sin A\cos A\sin B\cos B)=$$

$$=\sin^2A\,(1-\cos^2B)+\sin^2B\,(1-\cos^2A)-2\sin A\cos A\sin B\cos B=$$

$$=2\sin^2A\sin^2B-2\sin A\cos A\sin B\cos B=1\iff$$

$$\iff2\sin^2A\sin^2B-1=2\sin A\cos A\sin B\cos B\to$$

$$\to(2\sin^2A\sin^2B-1)^2=4\sin^2A\cos^2A\sin^2B\cos^2B\iff$$

$$\iff4\sin^4A\sin^4B-4\sin^2A\sin^2B+1=4\sin^2A(1-\sin^2A)\sin^2B(1-\sin^2B)\iff$$

$$\iff4x^2y^2-4xy+1=4x(1-x)y(1-y)\iff\ldots\iff x^2+(y-2)x+\frac1{4y}=0.$$

Now we have ourselves a quadratic equation in *x*, with *y* as a parameter, where *x* is $\sin^2A$, and *y* is $\sin^2B$. Could you take it from here ? :-)

Answer (score 0):

From my comment,

$$\cos C=\frac{-\cos(A-B)\pm\sqrt{\cos^2(A-B)+4}}2$$

For a non-trivial triangle, $\displaystyle 0<C<\pi\implies -1<\cos C<1$

Now as $\displaystyle |A-B|<\pi,\cos(A-B)>0 \implies \cos(A-B)+\sqrt{\cos^2(A-B)+4}>2$

Now if $\cos C_1,\cos C_2$ are the roots of $\cos^2C+\cos(A−B)\cos C-1=0$

$\displaystyle\implies  \cos C_1=\frac{-\cos(A-B)-\sqrt{\cos^2(A-B)+4}}2<-1 $

$\displaystyle\implies  -\cos C_1>1$

and $\displaystyle\cos C_1\cos C_2=-1\iff \cos C_2=\frac1{-\cos C_1}<1$

So, we shall always find a valid $C_2,$ for each pair of $A,B$ lies in $(0,\pi)$